# Infant cries and stiffens a like board when sat down

Tags: toddler

Hello parents of the stack,

My lovely 11-month old daughter, since learning to crawl, detests being sat down in her high chair to eat, or on the toilet to eliminate. She does this stiffening move to become flat like a board so that you can't bend her to sit. She just wails to boot which makes the struggle to get her seated that much more enjoyable.
We've employed a couple tricks that help to a moderate extent. We've given her toys in her hands(little cups) while trying to set her down. This distracted her enough to often plant her but in the chair. However, she's got to the point where she knows that schtick. Anyone have any other hacks for dealing with the stiffening, refusing to sit infant? Thanks Parents!

Comment: Good question! I'll be curious to see the answers.

Comment: Does she do it in a "fussy" way or in a "joking" way?

Comment: There's no joke about it. She doesn't want to sit. Once she's sitting, she's usually cool within 10 seconds.

Comment: Couple clarifying questions: (1) how old [~8-10 months?], and (2) can you get her into a car seat without trouble [i.e., is it just the high chair and potty she hates]?

Comment: Hi Erica, 1) She's 11 months old. 2)She's not a big fan of the car seat either. She complains about it, but her struggle is about 1/4 the other battles.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like my daughter at that age, who's now 5 years old.  In my daughter's case, it was here moro reflex that caused her to avoid sitting.  Basically, the moving backward made her feel like she was in a backward free fall.

Try this: lean her back into the chair **very** slowly, with her head and back supported by your hand.  If that doesn't work then attempt to roll her, from laying on her stomach, into a chair from the side, if possible.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

***Update***

Our daughter has quit battling us when we set her down. It is not longer the battle it used to be to set her on the toilet and high chair. Must have been just a phase or something.